# MAUI Binding iOS delegate classes that have to inherit from nsobject

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin.ios, maui

I am binding an iOS framework library to MAUI. I encounter the following error when I instanciate a "delegate" class in MAUI

```
System.Exception: Could not create an native instance of the type 'Wysiwys_framework_to_DOTNET.WYSSignatureProcessDelegate': the native class hasn't been loaded.
```

I have the same error for another delegate class. But all other binded classes are working fine.

The sharpie output is :

```
// @protocol WYSSignatureProcessDelegate <NSObject>
[Protocol]
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
interface WYSSignatureProcessDelegate
{
    // @required -(void)documentPreparedForSignature:(NSData * _Nonnull)documentDigest withReason:(NSString * _Nonnull)reason;
    [Abstract]
    [Export ("documentPreparedForSignature:withReason:")]
    void DocumentPreparedForSignature (NSData documentDigest, string reason);
}
```

My C# declaration is :

```
private class SignatureProcessDelegate : WYSSignatureProcessDelegate
{
    public event EventHandler<IDocumentPreparedEventArgs> DocumentPreparedEventHandler;

    public void DocumentPreparedForSignature(Stream documentDigest, string reason)
    {
        DocumentPreparedEventHandler?.Invoke(this, new DocumentPreparedEventArgs(documentDigest, reason));
    }
}
```

What I noticed is using the same delegate class in xCode require to add "NSObject" as parent class. If not, the following compilation error is shown :

```
import Foundation

class SignatureProcessDelegate : WYSSignatureProcessDelegate {
}

//Compilation error : Cannot declare conformance to 'NSObjectProtocol' in Swift; 'SignatureProcessDelegate' should inherit 'NSObject' instead
```

In xCode the following declaration compile fine and works fine :

```
import Foundation

class SignatureProcessDelegate : NSObject, WYSSignatureProcessDelegate {
}
```

But in C# we cannot have multiple base class, I cannot do this :

```
private class SignatureProcessDelegate : NSObject, WYSSignatureProcessDelegate
{
    //...
```

Any idea to help please ?